# select elements with the name attribute name in special xml structure

Tags: c#, xml, selectnodes

below is the structure of my xml document. I just want to first take the value of every node `<attribute name="a">` then make a comparison of it with a given value. However I don't how to locate `<attribute name="a">` of each node using xml selectnodes in c#. Google searches don't show any working solutions.

```
<nodes>     
 <node name = "node1">      
  <attribute name="a">This is node1 a</attribute>
  <attribute name="b">This is node1 b</attribute>
 </node>
 <node name = "node2">      
  <attribute name="a">This is node2 a</attribute>
  <attribute name="b">This is node2 b</attribute>
 </node>
 ...
</nodes>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the XML markup in your question represents your whole document, you can do:

```
XmlNodeList attrElements
    = yourDocument.SelectNodes("/nodes/node/attribute[@name='a']");
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use Linq to XML, something like the following:

```
string xml = "<nodes>...";

var results = from node in XDocument.Parse(xml).Descendants()
          where node.Name == "attribute"
          select node.Value;
```

You could then loop through the results as required.

There is a nice [Linq to XML overview here](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx) too.

Answer (score 3):

Use Linq to XML:

```
XElement xml = XElement.Load("test.xml");
var myNodes = xml.Descendants("attribute")
                 .Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "a");
```

To retrieve the values instead of the nodes:

```
var myValues = xml.Descendants("attribute")
                  .Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "a")
                  .Select(x => x.Value);
```

Comment: consolewriteline(myvalues) works strangely: I got: System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,
System.String]

Comment: You have to print out the items not the enumeration: `foreach(var item in myValues) Console.WriteLine(item);`

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the `System.Xml.XmlDocument` class for my xml parsing.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.load("myfilename.xml");
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("\\attribute[name='a']")
```

You should have a look at some XPath reference to be sure that you're getting the xpath string right http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx