# Retrieve Value from Xml file C#

Tags: c#

I have an XML file which contains following lines

```
<string name="accept">Accept</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="app_name">Val</string>
```

How can I get value of `app_name` string which is `Val` in C#. I tried XML parser but it doesn't work.

Comment: did you try this ?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c

Comment: Show us your entire XML structure.  What you posted isn't enough.

Comment: Full xml contains same such things string name something and some value...

Comment: No not a duplicate of that ... That xml layout is very much different than this...

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898121/select-elements-with-the-name-attribute-name-in-special-xml-structure

Comment: "That xml layout is very much different than this" - the expectation is that you do research and amend existing solutions as required. Stack Overflow isn't about handing you answers on a plate without you doing research.

Comment: @KaustubhPatange _it doesn't work_ is not a good way to ask a question. You should show what you did, and _in what way_ it doesn't work. Then we can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XmlDocument and an XPath statement in the SelectSingleNode method to retrieve this information.  Here is an example:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
var accept = doc.SelectSingleNode("//string[@name='accept']").InnerText;
var actionSettings = doc.SelectSingleNode("//string[@name='action_settings']").InnerText;
var appName = doc.SelectSingleNode("//string[@name='app_name']").InnerText;
```

Here is a tutorial on XPath syntax:  https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

UPDATE: @jon-skeet suggested using LINQ.  Should you choose to do that, your code might look something like:

```
var element = XElement.Parse(xml);
var accept = element.Descendants("string").Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "accept").Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
var actionSettings = element.Descendants("string").Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "action_settings").Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
var appName = element.Descendants("string").Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "app_name").Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I'd *strongly* encourage using LINQ to XML instead of XmlDocument, and only using XPath when you really need to - I see no benefit in doing that here. The result is fiddly and error-prone code.

Comment: @JonSkeet LINQ would work fine as well, I've updated the response to include a code sample of that approach.